# Placing two icons from fontawesome5 above each other

Tags: fontawesome, overset

Normally you can do 
`$\overset{a}{b}$` which results in :

[image: a above b]

Is there a way to do something similar using icons from the fontawesome5 package? if I try `$\overset{\faEye}{\faHeartbeat}$` I get the following:

[image]

Comment: Why math mode? Normally I would use a tabular.

Comment: I need to place text next to it in a section header.

Comment: why should that be a problem?

Comment: You *can* use `\overset`, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\overset{\mbox{\faEye}}{\mbox{\faHeartbeat}}$ or
$\overset{\text{\faEye}}{\text{\faHeartbeat}}$
\end{document}`, but I'd agree with @UlrikeFischer that there are likely better ways.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat putting it inside `\mbox` did the trick. Thanks! do you want to add this as an answer so I would accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cannot use the font awesome symbols in math mode. So, if you wish to use them in some math construction like `\overset`, say, you need to switch to text mode. This can be done with `\mbox` or `\text` (from amsmath, which also respects the size of the surrounding).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\overset{\mbox{\faEye}}{\mbox{\faHeartbeat}}$ or
$\overset{\text{\faEye}}{\text{\faHeartbeat}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]